# left join with spring data jpa and querydsl

Tags: java, spring, jpa, join, querydsl

I am using spring data jpa and querydsl and trapped on how to write simple nice query to left join two tables.
Suppose I have an Project entity and a Task entity with OneToMany relationship defined in Project, I would like to do something like:

```
select * from project p left join task t on p.id = t.project_id where p.id = searchTerm
select * from project p left join task t on p.id = t.project_id where t.taskname = searchTerm
```

In JPQL, it should be:

```
select distinct p from Project p left join p.tasks t where t.projectID = searthTerm
select distinct p from Project p left join p.tasks t where t.taskName = searthTerm
```

I have a ProjectRepository interface, which extends JpaRepository and QueryDslPredicateExecutor.
That gives me access to method:

```
Page<T> findAll(com.mysema.query.types.Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)
```

I know that left join can be easily achieved by creating a new JPAQuery(entityManager). But I do not have entity manager explicitly injected with spring data jpa.
Is there nice and simple way to build a predicate with left join?
Wish someone here have experienced this and is able to give me an example.
Thank you.

Frey.

Comment: Could you express what you need in JPQL and not in SQL? I am now not sure if you need the left join for loading or something else.

Comment: Hi Timo, JPQL expression added as requested

Answer (score 11):

If you want to express a constraint on tasks then you can do it like this

```
QProject.project.tasks.any().id.eq(searchTerm)
```

If you want to express preloading of certain tasks instead via a left join you can't express that via a Predicate. A Predicate in Querydsl is a boolean expression for the where, join-on and having parts of the query.

Comment: Hi Timo, thanks for the reply. Do you mean that any() can only provide constraint, without loading the data from the foreign table?

Comment: Yes, this solution provides only a constraint on the results, it doesn't affect the loading