# QueryDSL and ManyToMany relationships

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, querydsl, predicate

In a project I have the following entities : templates which have template parts which are connected to keywords. Both of these relationships are `@ManyToMany`. Some code :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEMPLATE")
public class TemplateEntity extends SystemFlagEntity {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "TEMPLATEPART_CATALOGUE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_FK_TEMPLATE", referencedColumnName = "C_I_IDF"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_FK_TEMPLATEPART", referencedColumnName = "C_I_IDF"))
    Set<TemplatePartEntity> templatePartsCatalogue = new HashSet<>();

}

@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEMPLATEPART")
public class TemplatePartEntity extends SystemFlagEntity {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "TEMPLATEPART_KEYWORD",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_FK_TEMPLATEPART"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_FK_KEYWORD"))
    Set<KeywordEntity> keywords = new HashSet<>();

}

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "KEYWORD")
public class KeywordEntity extends LabeledEntity {

    ...

}
```

Then I try to find the keywords related to some template with a given ID. I do this with `QueryDSL` using this predicate :

```
public Iterable<KeywordEntity> findCatalogueKeywordsForTemplate(Long id) {
    return findAll(
        QKeywordEntity.keywordEntity.in(QTemplateEntity.templateEntity.templatePartsCatalogue.any().keywords)
            .and(QTemplateEntity.templateEntity.id.eq(id))
    );
}
```

For some reason the predicate doesn't process well at all. I get this error when trying to call the method :

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
> templateEntity.templatePartsCatalogue is not mapped [select
> keywordEntity\nfrom
> mypackage.core.domain.model.KeywordEntity
> keywordEntity\nwhere exists (select 1\nfrom
> templateEntity.templatePartsCatalogue as
> templateEntity_templatePartsCatalogue_0\nwhere keywordEntity member of
> templateEntity_templatePartsCatalogue_0.keywords) and
> templateEntity.id = ?1]; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
> templateEntity.templatePartsCatalogue is not mapped [select
> keywordEntity\nfrom
> mypackage.core.domain.model.KeywordEntity
> keywordEntity\nwhere exists (select 1\nfrom
> templateEntity.templatePartsCatalogue as
> templateEntity_templatePartsCatalogue_0\nwhere keywordEntity member of
> templateEntity_templatePartsCatalogue_0.keywords) and
> templateEntity.id = ?1]

It looks like it doesn't process the `@ManyToMany` associations well. Any idea on how to fix this problem? I know I can use `JPAQuery` explicitely, but I'd like to use a `Predicate` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I misunderstood the way the Predicate works after seeing this answer by [`QueryDSL`'s creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077155/left-join-with-spring-data-jpa-and-querydsl/23092294#23092294).
This query works without needing to explicitely define many-to-many association tables :

```
public Iterable<KeywordEntity> findCatalogueKeywordsForTemplate(Long id) {
    return new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
            .select(QKeywordEntity.keywordEntity)
            .from(QTemplateEntity.templateEntity)
            .innerJoin(QTemplateEntity.templateEntity.templatePartsCatalogue, QTemplatePartEntity.templatePartEntity)
            .innerJoin(QTemplatePartEntity.templatePartEntity.keywords, QKeywordEntity.keywordEntity)
            .where(interceptPredicate(QTemplateEntity.templateEntity.id.eq(id)))
            .distinct()
            .fetch();
}
```